# OpenCV VideoCapture issue

Tags: python, opencv

I can't seem to figure out why I am being returned a NumPy array with values of 0 instead of actual numbers. When the program is executed it returns True so I know that python is able to read the VideoCapture object.

Could there something wrong I am doing?

```
import cv2,time

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check, frame = video.read()

print(check)
print(frame)

time.sleep(3)
video.release()
```

I do also get a message `[ WARN:0] terminating async callback` am not sure why I am getting this message.

My output for the program when executed is shown below.

```
True
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Updated Code (Still facing issues):

```
import cv2,time
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print('video.isOpened() =', video.isOpened())
check, frame = video.read()
np.set_printoptions(threshold='inf')
print(check)
print(frame)

time.sleep(3)
video.release()
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `0` in `video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to a local video file in my computer, and your code is able to read the video and output meaningful `numpy` arrays.
So I think your `python` code is fine.
Usually `0` in `VideoCapture` refers to the default video camera on your computer, could be a built-in webcam on your laptop, or an external one plugged in via e.g. USB. Would you please check whether that is functioning correctly?
You can add

```
print 'video.isOpened() =', video.isOpened()
```

after the line you create the video to see whether it's been successfully opened.

It would be also helpful to print every pixel value by setting `numpy`'s print option using

```
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold='inf')
```

so that you can check if you're getting literally all zeros or it's just mostly zeros with nonzero values not shown, which could be the case if your camera's covering cap is not open.

Example code to help your debugging:

```
import cv2,time
import numpy
import sys
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)

video = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/.../opencv-3.1.0/samples/data/768x576.avi")
print 'video.isOpened() =', video.isOpened()
check = True
count = 0
while check and count < 100:
    check, frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    count += 1
    cv2.waitKey(10)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('frame.png', frame)

print(check)
print(frame)

time.sleep(3)
video.release()
```

Comment: I placed `print('video.isOpened() =', video.isOpened())` right after I did `VideoCapture(0)` and it returns `true`. However, I placed `np.set_printoptions(threshold='inf')` right after the `print` and it gives me errors. Am I placing the 2nd line of code incorrectly?

Comment: What is the error message? Have you imported numpy? If not please add to the top `import numpy as np`

Comment: I see, could be a version/platform thing. Then you can try using `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
` as suggested by the error message. The other option is to `cv2.imshow` the `frame`, or  `cv2.imwrite` your `frame` to a local file and open it up to check whether it's completely black. Anyway, are you expecting very dark frames? Please consider also adding a `while` loop to read the camera in real time, and `imshow` it on screen, and move in front of the camera, and see if there's any motion in the `imshow` window.

Comment: I think it was the platform I was using, I tried a different platform and did not experience this. Thank you for the help!